# How to make WCF client use the same data types as the WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-3.5, client-server

I have a .NET WCF service that services only .NET WCF clients (all .NET 3.5, no interoperability, via TCP, binary encoding).
Using svcutil.exe the composite types that are used by the data members of the service are generated as part of the proxy.cs class used by the clients.

However, what to do if I wanted to reference the same types declared on the server/WCF side?
Scenario:
three assemblies: client.exe, wcfobjects.dll and wcfservice.dll
--> the wcfservice.dll references wcfobjects.dll
--> the client too references wcfobjects.dll

How can I generate a proxy that does NOT include the types used by the service?
Is that possible?
Thanks.

**Found this answer:** 
in order for svcutil.exe to NOT generate the types in the client proxy, you need to explicitly reference the wcfobjects.dll at the prompt:

**svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /async /tcv:Version35 /language:C# /r:\wcfobjects.dll /out:\Proxy.cs /config:\App.config**

Thanks again.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312264/why-wont-vs2010-rc-use-my-existing-types-when-i-add-a-service-reference

Comment: old, i know, but for anyone passing by: since you have access to the assembly with the types in the contract, and probably the contract itself, i would consider deriving from [ClientBase<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "Add Service Reference" dialog, on the "Advanced" tab, specify "Reuse existing types".

Comment: What about doing this using svcutil.exe?

Comment: I'm sure you can do it, I just haven't done it before. `svcutil /?` and go from there.